# Check if only specific properties of 2 objects are equal

Tags: java, functional-programming, guava

Say I have a a class `Person` (assume all of the properties can be set and can also be null):

```
public class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String secondName;
  private Address address;

  public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
  public String getSecondName() { return secondName; }
  public String getAddress() { return address; }
}
```

If I have two instances of `Person`, and I want to check if they both have the same `firstName` and `secondName`, I cannot simply call `equals()` as that will also check `address` for equality (and any other properties for that matter).

I would have to write a function like this:

```
boolean areNamesEqual(Person person1, Person person2) {
  if(person1 == null || person2 == null) {
    return person1 == person2;
  }
  if(person1.getFirstName() != null ? !person1.getFirstName().equals(person2.getFirstName()) : person2.getFirstName() != null) {
    return false;
  }
  if(person1.getSecondName() != null ? !person1.getSecondName().equals(person2.getSecondName()) : person2.getSecondName() != null) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Is there any cleaner way to express this? It feels like Java is making jump through quite a few hoops to express this simple idea. I have started looking at Google Guava, and have seen I can use `Objects.equal()` to improve matters:

```
boolean areNamesEqual(Person person1, Person person2) {
  if(person1 == null || person2 == null) {
    return person1 == person2;
  }
  if(Objects.equal(person1.getFirstName(), person2.getFirstName())) {
    return false;
  }
  if(Objects.equal(person1.getSecondName(), person2.getSecondName())) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

But I still have to check for the Person objects themselves being null, and write getFirstName() and getSecondName() twice each. It feels like there must be a better way expressing this.

Code like this would be ideal:

```
(person1, person2).arePropertiesEqual(firstName, secondName)
```

With this I don't have check for null anywhere, I don't have to return early, and I don't have to write `firstName` or `secondName` more than once.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of "better" are you trying to achieve? Shorter, more versatile, etc.?

Comment: why not overriding hash method with the properties you want to compare and then comparing the hashcodes? I believe this has even better performance. You avoind all the comparisons and replace it with one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Java (at least before Java 8 and the lambdas) and Guava, you won't get far as Java is not a functional language. See the [Caveats section in Functional Explained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained#Caveats) in the Guava Wiki for an extra opinion.

Actually, you can do it, but at the cost of more code, so you should really evaluate whether you need it. Something like:

```
private <T> boolean arePropertiesEqual(T t1, T t2, Function<T, ?>... functions) {
    if (t1 == null || t2 == null) {
        return t1 == t2; // Shortcut
    }
    for (Function<T, ?> function : functions) {
        if (!Objects.equal(function.apply(t1), function.apply(t2))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static class PersonFirstNameFunction 
        implements Function<Person, String> {
    @Override
    public String apply(Person input) {
        return input.getFirstName();
    }
}

private static class PersonLastNameFunction
        implements Function<Person, String> {
    @Override
    public String apply(Person input) {
        return input.getLastName();
    }
}

private void someMethod(Person p1, Person p2) {
    boolean b = arePropertiesEqual(p1, p2, 
            new PersonFirstNameFunction(), new PersonLastNameFunction());
}
```

Note: I've neither compiled nor run the code above, it probably has at least warnings due to the use of generic arrays (in the varargs).

It's already shorter with Java 8, looking something like:

```
private <T> boolean arePropertiesEqual(T t1, T t2, Function<T, ?>... functions) {
    if (t1 == null || t2 == null) {
        return t1 == t2; // Shortcut
    }
    for (Function<T, ?> function : functions) {
        if (!Objects.equals(function.apply(t1), function.apply(t2))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void someMethod(Person p1, Person p2) {
    boolean b = arePropertiesEqual(p1, p2,
            Person::getFirstName, Person::getLastName);
}
```

Note that here it's using `java.util.Objects` and `java.util.functions.Function`, not Guava.

---

Now, is that really "better" than the imperative code?

Comment: It's not really any better than the imperative code, I agree. But the only reason is the hoops you must jump through to express the function in code. Perhaps Java lambdas will make expressing it more syntactically sane

Comment: I already wrote the version using lambdas, so you can already decide if it's saner to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a moderately shorter version of your function:

```
public boolean areNamesEqual(Person p1, Person p2)  {
   return  (person1 != null  &&  person2 != null  &&
      Objects.equal(p1.getFirstName(), p2.getFirstName())  &&
      Objects.equal(p1.getSecondName(), p2.getSecondName()));
}
```

Comment: You'll want to replace your second `return` by a `&&`.

Comment: No, the null checks on the `Person`s are not redundant, to avoid getting an NPE when accessing the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean areNamesEqual(Person person1, Person person2) {
    if (person1 == null || person2 == null) {
        return person1 == person2;
    }
    return person1.getFirstName() == null
        ? person2.getFirstName() == null
        : person1.getFirstName().equals(person2.getFirstName());
}
```

Otherwise you may use [Objects.equal](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html).

```
Objects.equal(person1.getFirstName(), person2.getFirstName())
```

Same for all other properties.

Comment: I mention Objects.equal() in my question, this is not an answer. I am asking if there are any further improvements to be made that clean up the code further

Comment: As [Matthew Hubble](http://stackoverflow.com/users/590032/matthew-hubble) mentioned he is not interested in Guavas `Objects` class.

Comment: @Harmiezz: Where did he mention that...?

Comment: @[Louis Wasserman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman) In the first comment of my answer or I understood it that way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pojomatic API that doesn't need to add much code.
http://www.pojomatic.org/pojomatic/index.html

before is the exampple you just need to annotate with autoproperty for pojo and @property for fields with a policy of 'Equals'

```
import org.pojomatic.Pojomatic;
import org.pojomatic.annotations.AutoProperty;

@AutoProperty
public class Person {
  @Property(policy = PojomaticPolicy.EQUALS)
  private final String firstName;
  @Property(policy = PojomaticPolicy.EQUALS)
  private final String lastName;
  private final int age;

  public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.age = age;
  }

  public String getFirstName() { return this.firstName; }
  public String getLastName() { return this.lastName; }
  public int getAge() { return this.age; }

  @Override 
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      return Pojomatic.equals(this, o);
  }

  @Override 
  public int hashCode() {
      return Pojomatic.hashCode(this);
  }

  @Override 
  public String toString() {
     return Pojomatic.toString(this);
  }
}
```

now only first name and last time are considered when you say person1.equals(person2)

Answer (score 0):

You may also use something more dynamic, via reflection, like the following.

```
public boolean isObjectPropertiesEqual(Class clazz, Object o0, Object o1, String... properties) {
    for (int i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        // Validate the property value
        String property = properties[i];
        if (property == null || property.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }

        // Convert to Java Bean property getter method name
        String getter = "get" + property.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + property.substring(1);

        // Check for equality
        try {
            Method method = clazz.getMethod(getter);
            Object value0 = method.invoke(o0);
            Object value1 = method.invoke(o1);
            if (!Objects.equals(value0, value1))
                return false;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Usage example:

```
isObjectPropertiesEqual(Person.class, person1, person2, "firstName", "secondName");
```

Answer (score -1):

Not really, no.  There is not a better way of expressing this.  "With this I don't have check for null anywhere" - well, it's too bad that checking nulls is a requirement.  I'm not sure why you have to check if null is equal to itself or if null is equal to the names of a Person, or why people have null instead of names.  That all seems like nonsense to me but you probably have a good reason.

You can't avoid repeating the accessors for firstName and lastName with less code than you've already written.  If you put the method on the Person class itself you should at least be able to avoid the "get" and "()" by using the private fields directly.  Here is some code that is no better than the code in your question:

```
public static boolean areBothNullOrBothNonNullAndNamesEqual(Person a, Person b) {
  if (a == null || b == null) {
    return a == b;
  }
  return Objects.equals(a.firstName, b.firstName)
      && Objects.equals(a.lastName, b.lastName);
}
```